# How to group classes from Jacoco report using Ant

Tags: java, ant, jacoco

I'm using Jacoco with Ant to generate code coverage reports for classes from a few modules.

sourceDir/

- module1/

  - target/classes/class11
  - target/classes/class12
- module2/

  - target/classes/class21
  - target/classes/class22

Ant task:
...

`<property name="src.dir" location="sourceDir"/>`

```
<target name="report">
    <jacoco:report>

        <executiondata>
            <file file="${result.exec.file}" />
        </executiondata>

        <structure name="JaCoCo Report">
            <classfiles>
                <fileset dir="${src.dir}" includes="**/target/classes/**" />
            </classfiles>
            <sourcefiles encoding="UTF-8">
                <fileset dir="${src.dir}" />
            </sourcefiles>
        </structure>

        <html destdir="${result.report.dir}" />
        <csv destfile="${result.report.dir}/report.csv" />
        <xml destfile="${result.report.dir}/report.xml" />
    </jacoco:report>
</target>
```

Running Ant task I get a report similar to this:

Report

- class11
- class12
- class21
- class22

Would like to get something like this:

Report:

- module1/

  - class11
  - class12
- module2/

  - class21
  - class22

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting documentation at http://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/ant.html :

> The structure can be refined with a hierarchy of group elements. This way the coverage report can reflect different modules of a software project. For each group element the corresponding class and source files can be specified separately. For example:
>
> ```
> <structure name="Example Project">
>     <group name="Server">
>         <classfiles>
>             <fileset dir="${workspace.dir}/org.jacoco.example.server/classes"/>
>         </classfiles>
>         <sourcefiles>
>             <fileset dir="${workspace.dir}/org.jacoco.example.server/src"/>
>         </sourcefiles>
>     </group>
>     <group name="Client">
>         <classfiles>
>             <fileset dir="${workspace.dir}/org.jacoco.example.client/classes"/>
>         </classfiles>
>         <sourcefiles>
>             <fileset dir="${workspace.dir}/org.jacoco.example.client/src"/>
>         </sourcefiles>
>     </group>
>     ...
> </structure>
> ```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Godin. This is an obvious way to go but I was more interested if there is a way to dynamically derive group names from parent directories e.g. 'module1' and put the classes under those groups in the report. The are a lot of modules in my project so it's quite cumbersome to define all of them.

Comment: @SimonasKakštys `for` loop over modules + `antcall` to generate separate report for each ; or main `build.xml` generates and calls `build.xml` that will be creating single report ; or custom report generator - http://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/examples/java/ReportGenerator.java